# jquery viewport Проверка на ширину экрана / запуск скрипта

Tags: jquery, viewport

Общими усилиями изменил скрипт https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPozWM . Скрипт делает копию главного меню сайта при скроллинге и добавляет фиксед. Сейчас идет проверка на вюпорт при ресайзе окна, если окно меньше 768 пикселей, скрипт не запускаеться. НО, при стандартной открытии( без ресайза экрана ) срипт ваще не работает. Помогите пожалуйста подправить скрипт. **Задача А)** что бы при открытии страницы, если вюпорт больше 768 пикселей скрипт работал сразу.
*Б) (желательно, но не обязательно)*, при ресайзе - скрипт если запустился то он уже работает постоянно не зависимо от вюпорта. Задача что бы если возвращаемся в зону меньше 768 пиксей скрипт выключался.

```
var resizeTimeout;

window.onresize = function(){
  clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(initAfterResize, 1000);
};

function initAfterResize(){

  window.ScreenWidth = $(window).width();
  window.ScreenHeight = $(window).height();

  if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {

    // clone-menu start here. Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
    $('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();

    scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


    function stickIt() {

      var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
      orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               

      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
        // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

        // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
        orgElement = $('.original');
        coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
        leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
        widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
        $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
        $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
      } else {
        // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
        $('.cloned').hide();
        $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
      }
    }
  } 

}
```

Comment: за что минусы то? я не далеко не силен в программировании

Comment: правильный ответ внизу, может кому надо будет. Через лоад при загрузке документа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

УРА, я сам нашел ответ! поздравтье меня.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).load(function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= '768'){
          // Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
          $('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();

          scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


          function stickIt() {

            var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
            orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               

            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
              // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

              // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
              orgElement = $('.original');
              coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
              leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
              widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
              $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
              $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
            } else {
              // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
              $('.cloned').hide();
              $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
            }
          }
         }
      });
    });
```